# Which pronoun should be used to refer back to actions?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

Which word is better suited to reference an action? For example,

> Setting appearance of each report component is too long process. It’s
>   easier to use styles for **it**.

or

> Setting appearance of each report component is too long process. It’s
>   easier to use styles for **this**.

I'm trying to refer not to some object but to all previous sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'This' is the better choice, as it is a demonstrative pronoun. 'It', on the other hand, is a personal pronoun, rendering it less than ideal.

I also notice that your example is slightly awkward. Might I humbly suggest:

> Setting the appearance of each report component is a long process. It's easier to use styles for this.

Comment: Isn't *this* also singular?

Comment: Yes, it was a silly brain fart. I changed my reasoning to be more appropriate. And here I was hoping that with only five views, no one saw that.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. It's very helpful for me as your whole answer.

Comment: You're quite welcome, @HighAley . Also, since I notice you're new here, if you like someone's answer (or dislike it), you can click the arrows to give or take away votes. Also, if you decide an answer fits your needs, you can click the checkmark to mark the matter closed in your book.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: I apologize. I'd forgotten that.